# SPFX extension does not load on Site Contents page

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, css, spfx-extensions, site-contents

I've developed a CSS injector application customizers that loads the.css file from the style library and applies it to the website. However, I discovered that the extension is not loaded when users are viewing the Site Contents page.

Is there a way to load the extension on the site content page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a known platform issue: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/8550